# Get length of each item in list c#

Tags: c#

I have a some string type variables that are contained in a list like so

```
new List<string>{ varFullName, varHouseNameNumber, varPostCode, varRelationship, varPercOfBenefit }
```

What I'd like todo is check the length of each item within the list, and return false if any item has a length of 0.

I have tried using something like `BenOneInput.Any(item => item.Length.Equals(0))` however as soon as 1 item in the list has a length greater than 0, the whole thing returns true.

Is this possible?

Comment: I’m not sure why you edited the question to remove the negation before the `Any` call because that should have been working.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use `All`

```
var allNonZero = values.All(x=>x.Lenght > 0);
```

It will check if all values have `Length` not being 0

OR as @Asad Saeeduddin

```
var allNonZero = !values.Any(x=>x.Length==0);
```

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong about the `Any` thing, I think both will perform the same. The `All` will probably short circuit if there is any contradiction.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin but it is another syntax option to do :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `var anyZero = values.Any(x => x.Length == 0)`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `All`

```
var all = list.All(x => x.Length > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The result is correct because Any() check if in list exist any item with length == 0. If exist it return true. You need just negate your result.

```
var list = new List<string> {"test", "", "test2"};
var result = !list.Any(item => item.Length.Equals(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<string> BenOneInput = new List<string>{ "varFullName", "varHouseNameNumber", "varPostCode", "varRelationship", "varPercOfBenefit" };
bool result = BenOneInput.All(item => !item.Length.Equals(0));
```

Answer (score -2):

You could do

```cs
string any;
for (i = 0; i > listname.length; i++) { 
    any = listname[i].ToString()
    Console.WriteLine(any.length);
}
```

Comment: This code is full of errors. For starters, it doesn't declare `i`. Then you mean `< listname.Length`, not `> listname.length`. It's missing a semicolon after the useless `ToString()` and at `any.length` you again replaced the upper L with a lower l. This code, if fixed, prints the length of all entries in the list, but doesn't act if any has length 0, which was requested by the question, Anyway, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [tour] and [answer].